# Symfony2 DI of lazy service and typehinting

Tags: symfony, repository, lazy-loading

In our application, we defined repositories as services like the following example:

```
company.repository:
    class: AppBundle\Entity\Company
    factory: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, getRepository]
    arguments:
        - AppBundle\Entity\Company
```

So that we could inject it in services where we only needed specific repositories instead of the whole entity manager. It was easier to test and made our services less coupled.

E.G:

```
company.service:
    class: AppBundle\Services\CompanyService
    arguments:
        - @company.repository
```

With the constructor type hinting it's dependencies:

```
<?php

use AppBundle\Entity\CompanyRepository

public function __construct(CompanyRepository $repo)
...
```

Now this list is starting to grow large and I was thinking of defining those repositories as `lazy` to gain some performance.

E.G:

```
company.repository:
    lazy: true
    class: AppBundle\Entity\Company
    factory: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, getRepository]
    arguments:
        - AppBundle\Entity\Company
```

At first sight, it seemed to work. But after some testing I found that the type hinting seems to have been broken by defining those services as `lazy`

An example Exception I receive after defining those repositories as lazy:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\EventListener\CompanyIdRequiredListener::__construct() must
>   be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\CompanyRepository, instance of
>   AppBundleEntityCompany_000000002d9713890000000167592edede1aa99e97f8c6a4a84b995db8a0c1e9
>   given

I'm honestly surprised by this exception as it seems that this is a simlar use case as described by the official Symfony documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/components/dependency_injection/lazy_services.html#why-lazy-services)

> In some cases, you may want to inject a service that is a bit heavy to
>   instantiate, but is not always used inside your object. For example,
>   imagine you have a NewsletterManager and you inject a mailer service
>   into it. Only a few methods on your NewsletterManager actually use the
>   mailer, but even when you don't need it, a mailer service is always
>   instantiated in order to construct your NewsletterManager.

Is this something fixable or is this a drawback of using lazy services.

I've though about:

- Interface type hinting might solve this problem ? (Is some work but I can live with it)
- Not use lazy services and accept a 'slower' application (Would be sad news)
- Stop injecting specific repositories and return to injecting the entitymanager (Feels really dirty and would break alot of tests)

Cookies for thoughs !

Comment: I have not used lazy repository services.  Does it work if you remove the typehint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have error in the repository service definition. Replace `class: AppBundle\Entity\Company` with `class: AppBundle\Entity\CompanyRepository`.

Comment: Oh man I would've missed this even if I read it 100 times over. I feel so dumb right now, Thanks !

Comment: Interesting.  Normally the class: does not matter when when using a factory.  But I guess for lazy services the class is used to generate the proxy.  Be curious to see if using lazy repositories actually improves performance.  The proxies themselves add significant overhead and I don't really think repositories are all the heavy.  But who knows.

Comment: Some quick testing using apache bench resulted in a improvement of +/- 150 - 200 ms on avarage. (This was only 1 api endpoint). Looks promising but I will need to do more tests to come to a solid conclusion.